# Axios to generate Nuxt dynamic routes based on query

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I have dynamic pages' routes being generated in nuxt.config.js like this:

```
  generate:{
    routes: function () {
      return axios.get(apiUrl + '/pages')
        .then((res) => {
          return res.data.map(page => {
            return page.slug
          })
      })
    }
  }
```

This works fine, however, my pages have a name `"publish"` which can be true or false.

How can I filter them?
Thanks

Comment: `return page.plublish && page.slug`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found it, this seems to work!

```
  generate:{
    routes: function () {
      return axios.get(apiUrl + '/pages')
        .then((res) => {
          return res.data.filter(page => {
            return page.publish === true;
          }).map(page => {
            return page.slug
          })
      })
    }
  }
```